# How to create report (.sxw) with a boolean field?

Tags: report, odoo

I have a boolean field that I would like to show in the PDF if the value is 'TRUE' then print 'Head Office' but if 'False' then print 'Sub Branch'

```
<field name='is_branch'/>
```

in .sxw

```
[repeatIn(objects,'o')]]
[[(o.is_pk_branch=='TRUE') and 'Sub Branch' or 'Head Office']]
```

but in the PDF show just 'Head Office'
Some one please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
[[ (o.is_pk_branch==True and "Head Office") or "Head Office"]]
```

Comment: and i have more question 
If i want to hide this field if "o.is_pk_branch=='TRUE'" ?? [[ (o.partner_id.phone) or removeParentNode('para') ]]

Comment: just put it and see what output comes. do it experiment and you will learn better.

Comment: i want to hide field partner_id.phone if is_pk_branch==True 
i try 
[[(o.partner_id.phone) or removeParentNode('para') and (o.is_pk_branch==True)]]
but it doesn't work

Comment: try [[ (o.is_pk_branch==True) and (o.partner_id.phone) and removeParentNode('para') ]]

Comment: it's work on [[(o.is_pk_branch==True) and (o.partner_id.phone) or removeParentNode('para')]]
thank you for your advice again :)
you help me a lot